# How to get alerts about Speed Monitoring Cameras in GPS Maps Application?

Tags: maps, navigation, 8.0-oreo, driving-mode, here-maps

I am using Here Maps (Here WeGO), but I do not get any warnings about speed monitoring cameras. 
I would also like to pay for such a service. 
The application well informs already if you drive too fast.

I know there are some GPS devices which can give such alerts. 
I think TomTom, at least.

### Testing xavier_fakerat's proposal

I see now interaction with CamerAlert but have not tested when driven. 
It took some time for the program to relocate to Baltics from London. But

- Start here maps. Start then CamerAlert second time. The app crashes. It alerts all the time about unupdated maps although I just updated them.

I will go with Sygic.

OS: Android Oreo 8.0
Phone: OnePlus 3T
Region: Sweden, Finland, Norway, Baltics
Maps: Here We Go Maps, rarely Google Maps (because no easy offline use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need an additional tool for Speed Camera alerts or an alternative navigation tool with built-in speed cam alerts feature.

For the former, there are  some options from playstore but ideally you'd still want to keep Here WeGo so you could go for an application with an **overlay support/widget** that ensures you use your primary navigation app whilst still getting speed cam alerts in the background.

A few options present:

[CamerAlert](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pocketgpsworld.cameralert&hl=en) (from PocketGPSWorld) for a very up-to-date speed camera database; it is updated at least weekly and includes mobile sites. It can be used as **an overlay with any navigation app.**

> CamerAlert is a self-contained Speed and Red Light Camera warning
> system using data from the renowned PocketGPSWorld.com Speed Camera
> Database.
>
> It provides both **audible** and **visual warnings** as you
> approach a camera. Uniquely, when you are in a section of SPECs
> (Average Speed) cameras, CamerAlert displays your average speed
> between each camera in the zone.
>
> CamerAlert also utilises directional
> information to reduce the number of "False Alerts", you are only
> warned for cameras that monitor your direction of travel.

**Costs**:

> PocketGPSWorld subscribers can use their annual membership to keep the
> camera data up to date by linking their member details in the app.
>
> If you are not an existing subscriber you can subscribe in the app to
> ensure access the our regular updates. A subscription can be used on
> other GPS devices as well as the Android (maximum of three devices,
> one of which may be an Android or iPhone SmartPhone).
>
> **An annual subscription costs £19.99**

Learn more at the official [website](http://www.cameralert.com/)

---

Alternatively running other navigation apps' camera alerts application is worth a try, [Sygic Speed Cameras & Traffic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sygic.speedcamapp) or [TomTom Speed Cameras](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tomtom.speedcams.android.map) also serve similar purposes with the latter with overlay support.

**Sygic**:

> - offline database of more than 50 000 fixed speed cameras, average
>   speed checks and red light cameras in your app.
> - with Speed Camera's Premium, you can see your current speed, speed limits, and warnings also in other apps (Paid feature)

Pricing see [here](https://eshop.sygic.com/en/)

---

Tom tom speed cam app, see [here](https://www.tomtom.com/en_au/drive/maps-services/speed-cameras/) to learn more.

Also worth noting is that the regions in question are covered by these tools.

Comment: Which one do you recommend? I like open-source but I am also ready to pay for the service. - - Sygic seems to also have some info about gas prices which may be useful. - - There is also Copilot, but not sure if the function there.

Comment: Currently I use Sygic Maps, with speed cam alerts and the variety of features makes it a good choice together with its offline functionality. I have also noticed CamerAlert has a good reputation , which is why I included it on the list. I haven't tried Tom Tom however.

Comment: Please, see the question body. I will go with Sygic. You get 77% discount on the product when buying it now :)

Comment: What do you think about augmented reality on navigation? - - I think no at the moment because the screen should be transparent, and current solid screens affect too much driving if using too much.

Comment: Good point, also you can trial before making final decision to purchase. Agreed! Too much solid objects do distract quite often, but I think the reason for AR is that alerts and crucial info is delivered more accurately and faster, as they're visualised faster with the real-time camera.